# JAX: unable to jnp.where with known sizes inside a pmap

Tags: python, jax

I wanted to do a *pmap* of a given function, with 2D arrays that might (or might not) contain nan values.  That function must then apply some operations to the finite values that exist in each row (toy examples at the end of the post).

I know how many points (per row) contain NaNs, even before I /jax.jit/ anything. Thus, I should be able to:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp 
inds = jnp.where(jnp.isfinite(line), size= Finite_points_number)
```

but I am not able to pass the size of the elements into the *pmap*-ed function.

I have tried to:

i) pmap over over the list with the number of good points per row:

```py
data_array = jnp.array([
                   [1,2,3,4], 
                   [4,5,6, jnp.nan]
                  ]
                )

sizes = jnp.asarray((4, 3)) # Number of valid points per row

def jitt_function(line, N):
    """
    Over-simplified function to showcase the problem
    """
    inds = jnp.where(jnp.isfinite(line), size=N)
    return jnp.sum(line[inds])

pmap_func = jax.pmap(jitt_function,
                in_axes=(0, 0)
         )

pmap_func(data_array, sizes)
```

and it fails with

> The size argument of jnp.nonzero must be statically specified to use jnp.nonzero within JAX transformations. The error occurred while tracing the function jitt_function at [...] for pmap. This concrete value was not available in Python because it depends on the value of the argument 'N'.

ii) I have also tried to turn the number of points (N) into a static argument:

```py
jitt_function = jax.jit(jitt_function, static_argnames=("N",))

pmap_func = jax.pmap(jitt_function,
                in_axes=(0, 0)
         )
```

> ValueError: Non-hashable static arguments are not supported, as this can lead to unexpected cache-misses. Static argument (index 1) of type <class 'jax.interpreters.partial_eval.DynamicJaxprTracer'> for function jitt_function is non-hashable.

Even if I managed to transform this into a static argument, I would still need to "know" the line number, so that I could access the correct number of good points.

**Question:** Is there any way for me to do this within jax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a different number of points per `pmap` batch, then the number is not static. The result of your intended operation would be a ragged array (i.e. a 2D array whose rows have differing numbers of elements) and ragged arrays are not supported in JAX.

If you actually have a static number of elements—meaning an equal number in every batch—then you can use the `size` argument of `jnp.where` to do this computation. It might look something like this:

```py
from functools import partial

def jitt_function(line, N):
    """
    Over-simplified function to showcase the problem
    """
    inds = jnp.where(jnp.isfinite(line), size=N, fill_value=0)
    return jnp.sum(line[inds])

pmap_func = jax.pmap(partial(jitt_function, N=4))

pmap_func(data_array)
```

If you have fewer than the specified number of entries in each batch, then one option is to specify the `fill_value` argument to `jnp.where` to pad the output. In this case, since you are taking the sum along each dimension, a fill value of zero returns the expected result.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. Unfortunately, my use case is more involved than the sum, which means that I can't do that!